# Kafka docker configuration failing with error : No security protocol defined for listener PLAINTEXT

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

This is how my docker file looks like,

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '9093:9093'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,EXTERNAL://:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=CLIENT
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_PROTOCOL=PLAINTEXT
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

When I run the docker file below is the error I am getting

```
kafka_1      | [2022-09-05 18:51:52,189] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
kafka_1      | [2022-09-05 18:51:54,618] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
kafka_1      | [2022-09-05 18:51:54,810] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)
kafka_1      | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error creating broker listeners from 'PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093': No security protocol defined for listener PLAINTEXT
kafka_1      |  at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.listenerListToEndPoints(CoreUtils.scala:273)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.effectiveAdvertisedListeners(KafkaConfig.scala:1924)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.validateValues(KafkaConfig.scala:2033)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1997)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1471)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:1394)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.Kafka$.buildServer(Kafka.scala:67)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:87)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

I have followed the instructions mentioned at below docker help,

https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka/

Please advise how can I fix it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I followed the instructions at this page and it worked as expected,

https://developer.confluent.io/quickstart/kafka-docker/

Comment: That's not the same container, though

Answer (score 1):

Your error is most likely coming from `KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=CLIENT` or `KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CLIENT:PLAINTEXT`

You've not defined `CLIENT` as a listener.

Also, both of your advertised listeners are localhost. Using an IP address doesn't change that... The bitnami Kafka container readme has instructions how to separate internal and external listener addresses